# How to connect inout port of other module in other module?

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to understand verilog with https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/bidirectional-tristate-in-out-port-in-Vivado/td-p/352239, especially, inout port.

I've implemented as the below for understanding. But I think I've got something wrong to use the 'my_top' module in tb module

How to connect to between 'my_top' module in 'tb' module ?
also I want test the my_top module in tb module by using initial statement.

How to connect to see the working of my_top module in tb module?

```
module tb;

reg     data_tri;
reg     data_tx;
reg     data_rx;
wire    data_io;


my_top u_my_top(
  .data_tri (   data_tri            ),
  .data_tx  (   data_tx         ),
  .data_rx  (   data_rx         ),
  .data_io  (   data_io         )
  );

initial begin
#30 
//inout write 
data_tri = 0; 
data_tx = 1; 
//inout read 
data_tri = 1; 
data_io = 1;
end

endmodule


module my_top (
  input  data_tri,
  input  data_tx,
  output data_rx,
  inout  data_io
  );

assign data_io = (data_tri) ? 1'bZ : data_tx;
assign data_rx = data_io;

endmodule
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your example will not compile, because it is illegal to assign to a wire (`data_io`) in procedural code (ie that code inside an initial or always block).

Comment: @MatthewTaylor, ooops, sorry. I want to connect and use the my_top module from tb module. but I've stuck with some compile error as your comment. What am I supposed to do to connect between my_top module and tb module to use correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to drive a tristate signal (using a wire) in your testbench in exactly the same way as you did in your design:

```
assign data_io = (data_tri) ? data_txtb : 1'bZ;
```

So, for example:

```
module tb;

reg     data_tri;
reg     data_tx;
reg     data_txtb;
wire    data_rx;
wire    data_io;

  my_top u_my_top(
    .data_tri (   data_tri        ),
    .data_tx  (   data_tx         ),
    .data_rx  (   data_rx         ),
    .data_io  (   data_io         )
  );

  assign data_io = (data_tri) ? data_txtb : 1'bZ;

  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;

    //inout write 
    data_tri = 0; 
    data_tx = 1; 
    #30 
    data_tx = 0; 
    #30 
    data_tx = 1; 

    #30 
    //inout read 
    data_tri = 1; 
    data_txtb = 0; 
    #30 
    data_txtb = 1; 
    #30 
    data_txtb = 0; 
    #30; 
  end

endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/342E

Comment: aha~ let me check it.

Comment: sir, I do found that there is no 'z' value happens in simulation. but I think in the write time, data_rx might need to go 'z'. doesn't it make sense?

Comment: @that's because in my testbench I either drive from the testbench or from the design. If you want to change that, go ahead: have separate tristate enable signals (`data_tri`). In a real design you would want to avoid that situation: driving a 'Z' into the input of the gate is a very bad idea, because it turns both of the complimentary MOS transistors half on causing all sorts of problems.

Comment: Thanks sir I understand this.